# React Native map data acess

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question about react-native `MapViewDirection` with the expo.

I have my result received from the `onReady` function inside `MapViewDirection`.

I want to display the distance and duration field to the user.

```
 onReady={result => {

              console.log(result)
}};
```

I want to declare I am learning and am using someone else's code to practice. Below is full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 40.3788;
const LONGITUDE = -105.5143;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0192;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'AIzaSyAkwAlX2w0S3ba6OxBqr13JGDuYIi5GRZ8';

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      coordinates: [
        {
          latitude:40.3788,
          longitude:-105.5143,
        },

      ],
    };

    this.mapView = null;
  }

  onMapPress = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      coordinates: [
        ...this.state.coordinates,
        e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
      ],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: LATITUDE,
          longitude: LONGITUDE,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        ref={c => this.mapView = c}
        onPress={this.onMapPress}
      >
        {this.state.coordinates.map((coordinate, index) =>
          <MapView.Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} coordinate={coordinate} />
        )}
        {(this.state.coordinates.length >= 2) && (
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={this.state.coordinates[0]}
            waypoints={ (this.state.coordinates.length > 2) ? this.state.coordinates.slice(1, -1): null}
            destination={this.state.coordinates[this.state.coordinates.length-1]}
            apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            strokeWidth={3}
            strokeColor="hotpink"
            optimizeWaypoints={true}
            onStart={(params) => {
              console.log(`Started routing between "${params.origin}" and "${params.destination}"`);
            }}
            onReady={result => {

              console.log(result);

              this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(result.coordinates, {
                edgePadding: {
                  right: (width / 20),
                  bottom: (height / 20),
                  left: (width / 20),
                  top: (height / 20),
                }
              });
            }}
            onError={(errorMessage) => {
              // console.log('GOT AN ERROR');
            }}
          />
        )}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear Aashish, please say what's your exact desire? I don't understand what you want!

Comment: So I want to be able to get distance and time required to move from all selected marker on maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below given code you can get the distance between two locations using there latitude & longitude. We are using google distance matrix api here to get distance.

```
  getDistanceOneToOne(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) 
  {
    const Location1Str = lat1 + "," + lng1;
    const Location2Str = lat2 + "," + lng2;
    let GOOGLE_API_KEY = "API_KEY"
    let ApiURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"

    let params = `origins=${Location1Str}&destinations=${Location2Str}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`; // you need to get a key
    let finalApiURL = `${ApiURL}${encodeURI(params)}`;

    this.getDistance(finalApiURL).then((getDistance) => {
      console.log('Distance charges',getDistance);

      if (getDistance.status == "OK") 
      {

          let value = getDistance.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; //Distance 
          let time = getDistance.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value; //time
      }    
  });
  }

    getDistance = (url) => {
        return this.getDistanceCall(url)
    }

    getDistanceCall = (url) => {

        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then((response) => { return response.json(); })
            .catch((error) => {
                return error;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more where to use this on my screen code above. Please I am not able integrate.

Comment: @AashishSapkota first remove api key mentioned in your question. Just use Constant (API_KEY) while posting question on stackoverflow. So that no one other than you can use your api key.

Comment: @AashishSapkota first get the latitude and longitude of both your locations. and then call the getDistanceOnetoOne function mentioned above with these two latitude and longitude. You will get the distance and time estimate in between these two locations.